# Age vs career in natural science

Tags: graduate-school, career-path, age

Due to my country's education (we finish high school later than other countries), a year off, doing master's degree, I am finding myself in my first year of PhD in States   being 26 years old, possibly graduating when I am 30. I have recently become very anxious about my age, since scientific career has been always my goal, I feel like I am too old and behind everyone else. In Europe, where I am from, I have been told that age does not matter as much, and what matters is papers/scientific output, especially since the end of PhD, in support of me pursuing the doctoral degree in USA, where it takes longer. I am doing my PhD at one of the top tier schools in a very prolific group, where I am surrounded by people that got their PhD when they were 25... 
In addition I know from experience of me and others that in my field (physics) women are heavily biased against at all stages. Also, my field requires completion of usually 2 post-docs before applying for positions, which would take around 5 years.

I am looking for some input on this and **how realistic  my chances of staying in academia are**, **how much age matters when hiring for post-docs/faculty positions (in Europe)** and **how to cope with age related anxiety in academia**.

Comment: This ground has been covered pretty thoroughly in the [tag:age] tag.

Comment: I am asking for advice about European job market, with USA-long PhD done later than most peers, and also about coping.

Comment: @caitlyn If the question you want answered isn't covered by the prior questions, please ask a new one that focuses on the aspect that isn't covered.  It will also be most likely to get a good answer if you ask each sub-question in its own focused question (e.g., one for the USA-Europe transfer, and a different one about coping).

Comment: ok thank you! should I delete this one?

Comment: @caitlyn No need: StackExchange typically preserves duplicates because they are often different phrasing of the question that still help to direct people who are searching for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, age at graduation is not the most important factor for a career in academia. But assuming it was, then according to your estimate (30), you should be rather competitive.

> For the 2003 doctorate recipients, the median total time from
>   baccalaureate to doctorate was 10.1 years, while the median registered
>   time was 7.5 years and the median age at doctorate was 33.3 years.

[Time to Degree of U.S. Research Doctorate Recipients](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/infbrief/nsf06312/)

(Being 33 and just about to submit my thesis, I'm right on target.) Also notice that with your pre-PhD degree, you are already looking back at a  a few years of scientific education that your US peers lack, if they start grad school with a bachelors degree. Academic employers know this.

Maybe this is not a full answer to your question, but at least a consolation. Don't panic.

Comment: Watch out.  I think that 10.1 years/age 33.3 is so high because of the humanities.  Ph.D. in science and engineering is usually much less.

Comment: @GEdgar "Doctorate recipients in the S&E fields typically earn their degrees while in their early 30s; the median for all 2003 doctorate recipients in the S&E fields was 31.8 years old. In comparison, age at doctorate was 34.6 years in the humanities, 37.2 years in health, 43.5 years in education, and 37.5 years in the professional/other fields category."

Answer (score 0):

In the US it is illegal to discriminate in hiring based on age (or on gender).  So if your Ph.D. is superb, then you are in no trouble.

Comment: I want to go back to Europe after PhD. Also in my field people require 2 post-docs, which adds another ~5 years...